# Get information from website I don´t own

Tags: json, parsing

The title may seem a bit vague, allow me to explain.

I want to pull information from a website I do not own or have any control over,e.g.
 I would like to parse this data with JSON or similar.

I´m having a problem to understand parsing. Do the website administrators need to provide their data in JSON format in order to let me get that data?

Or can I get whatever data I want by providing an URL and the html-element of that particular piece of information?

Comment: You choose the parers based on the data format. If the information is provided as JSON, you use a JSON parser. If it is provided as HTML, you use an HTML parser. If it is XML, you use an XML parser, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain any data available publically in a site, just like a web browser would. But as is, not in the format you want it. You will have to parse and extract the information from the HTML code it gave to you or whatever format you are downloading it.

How exactly you're goin to do that will depend on many factors starting from the language you are using.

Comment: Ok, so I first have to parse the data using a HTML-parser(assuming the site don´t provide it in JSON) and then import it to my service? I´m doing a iOS-application with the data. UPDATE: The site provides an RSS feed, can I use that?

Comment: That will depend. It may be HTML but maybe you only need one piece or two of information from it, so theres no need to parse the entire document (which can be very coastly CPU-wise). Regular Expressions will assist you in easily extracting all needed information based on a known HTML template in most cases.